# WKInterfaceTable's didSelectRowAtIndex never gets called in WKInterfaceController

Tags: watchkit, ios8.2, wkinterfacetable, wkinterfacecontroller

I have a **WKInterfaceController** and I added a table as following:

```
// .h

@interface InterfaceController : WKInterfaceController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet WKInterfaceTable *table;
@end

// .m
- (void)table:(WKInterfaceTable *)table didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSLog(@"did select");
}

- (void)table:(WKInterfaceTable *)table
didSelectRowAtIndex:(NSInteger)rowIndex{
    NSLog(@"did select new");
}
```

However neither of the two methods gets called. I was unable to find any protocol declaration for WKInterfaceTable and neither any delegate property on the table.

Is there something that I am missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found out that the method was never called because I had set a segue to be triggered on selection of the row on Interface builder.

It seems that that by having no delegation and table protocols once you set a delegate it stops the didSelectRow method from being called.

Answer (score 3):

In Apple's WKInterfaceController document it states that if you do not have any actions or segues then the method called is:
- table:didSelectRowAtIndex:

If you use segues then the methods called are:

For buttons: 
- contextForSegueWithIdentifier:

For tables:
- contextForSegueWithIdentifier:inTable:rowIndex:

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4**

Here’s an example of selecting a WKInterfacetable row in a REST/JSON implementation.

Create a context property instance of the array class instead of using `self.pushController`.

```
override func table(_ table: WKInterfaceTable, didSelectRowAt rowIndex: Int) {
    let message = messageObjects[rowIndex]
    presentController(withName: "MessageView", context: message)
}
```